# I have a desktop file that won't launch even though the command it executes works when entered into the terminal. What's the deal here? (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: games, .desktop

I'm trying to launch Grim Fandango Remastered. I've found two commands that'll launch it.

The first is this thing:
`sh -c 'cd "/home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered/game/bin" && ./GrimFandango'`

Second is launching a file I named "alt_start.sh," which contains this:

```
cd "/home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered/game/bin"
./GrimFandango
exit
```

The game's supposed to run through a start.sh file, but all that does is throw this up:

```
Running Grim Fandango Remastered
Command line arg: ./GrimFandango
Absolute executable path: /home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered/game/bin/GrimFandango
Leaving working directory as: /home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered/game/bin
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi (search paths /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi (search paths /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  101
  Current serial number in output stream:  100
```

I've tried setting a .desktop file to run both of the forner, with and without displaying the terminal, and every time, it simply wouldn't boot.  I've tried moving alt_start to my home directory, but that doesn't help, either. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: Here's the contents of the .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Value=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Grim Fandango Remastered
GenericName=Grim Fandango Remastered
Comment=Grim Fandango Remastered
Icon=/home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered/support/icon.png
Exec=sh -c 'cd "/home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered/game/bin" && ./GrimFandango'
Categories=Game;
Path='/home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered'

Terminal=false
```

Edit 2: It's now suddenly claiming the ""/home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered" directory doesn't actually exist. The commands in the desktop file still work just fine, however.

Comment: So is it the desktop file you suspect to be the problem, or are you not able in any way to start the program? In the latter case, it is a problem with your application or the installation of it. In the former case, it could be a scripting issue. For one thing, you do not show the .desktop file you are referring to. Please clarify your question so the problem is more precisely defined.

Comment: The commands work fine in the terminal, it's just the .desktop that isn't working.

Comment: Edit your question to include that information, and post the .desktop file's content if that is the one which does not work.

Comment: Okay, it's in there.

Comment: Perhaps quote your icon path (it contains spaces), but I would be surprised if that is the cause why it does not work.

Comment: Out of nowhere it's started giving me a specific error. It claims the "/blah/blah/blah/Grim Fandango Remastered" directory doesn't actually exist. Once again, launching these commands through the terminal works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it. It's a hideous solution, but its good enough for me.

I renamed my alt_start.sh to grim_fandango.sh and changed by .desktop to this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Value=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Grim Fandango Remastered
GenericName=Grim Fandango Remastered
Comment=Grim Fandango Remastered
Icon=/home/adrian/GOG Games/Grim Fandango Remastered/support/icon.png
Exec=/home/adrian/grim_fandango_start.sh
Categories=Game;
Path=/home/adrian/

Terminal=false
```